# Postgresql slow query reproduction

Tags: postgresql

I've got a query that runs slowly in postgresql the first time it's run, subsequent runs are very fast.  Restarting postgresql and apache don't reproduce the slow runtime, but restarting the entire environment/system does.  Is there some other way to force whatever kind of caching is happening to expire without rebooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Linux, try restarting Postgres and:

```
echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```